# How to join the tables and get the combined information in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Currently, I have two tables in the Postgres as Category and Comment and I am using Python SQLAlchemy to fetch the data and expose the API.
But I am facing the issue in joining the tables, Can you please help me

Relation: Each category can have multiple comments

```
class Comment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    comment_desc = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    creation_date = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, server_default=db.func.current_timestamp(), nullable=False)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    category = db.relationship('Category', backref=db.backref('comments', lazy='dynamic' ))


class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    category_name = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True, nullable=False)


class CategorySchema(ma.Schema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    category_name = fields.String(required=True)


class CommentSchema(ma.Schema):
    id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    category_id = fields.Integer(required=True)
    comment_desc = fields.String(required=True, validate=validate.Length(1))
    creation_date = fields.DateTime()
```

Now I want to fetch details in the REST API as

category_id,category_name,comment_desc in the API, I have tried as below **but it didn't fetch me the combined details**

`category_comment_details = Comment.query.all(category_id,category_name,comment_desc).join(Category,Category.id= Comment.category_id)`

Answer (score 0):

The query code you pasted has a few issues:

1. The `query.all()` method takes no arguments and immediately executes the query, returning a list of results; so attempting to follow this up with a join doesn't make sense.
2. You're referring to the class members `category_id` (etc.) without qualifying them with the class names.
3. You need to use `==` in SQLAlchemy expressions, not `=`.

Assuming you want just the three columns you mentioned, this query should work:

```py
Comment.query.join(Comment.category).with_entities(
    Comment.category_id, Category.category_name, Comment.comment_desc
).all()
```